# How to edit SQL data by clicking on item to edit

Tags: php, sql, edit

So I have a table generated from SQL data and I want to be able to edit that data from the table without having to go to a separate form. I want the user to be able to select any part of the table and change it. Is that possible or will it have to be done using a separate form? Currently I have this which just displays the table:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_products");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Products:</th>
<th>Price:</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><a href=\"product.php?id=". $row['product_id'] ."\">" . $row['product_name'] . "</a></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['product_price'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: HTML5 has this: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Comment: That's the sort of thing I need but in the table.

Comment: Here is a table example: http://doodles.tev.net/contenteditable/

Comment: But getting that to update SQL data would be quite difficult.

Comment: Set up an AJAX function that updates the database.  Depending on your table structure, you can include required information in the `td` tags.